# Running Visual Studio Code from the CLI in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, visual-studio-code

I've downloaded and "installed" VSCode for Linux. I have placed the app in `/home/Christian/Apps/VSCode/` and symlinked the executable to `/usr/bin/code`.

When I use this method to start Code it hijacks the terminal (expected I guess) and also dumps a lot of STDERR stuff at the same time.

[image]

If I redirect STDERR to a file, for example like

```
code 2> ~/.logs/VSCode-`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S.log` &
```

Then I can get it to give me back my prompt, and it's silent (logging everything to the filename I gave it).

I was thinking of making this an alias, but then I realized I can't inject arguments ($1 $2 $3) in an alias. And I usually want to start code with `code filename.js` or `code .`.

What is the correct way to launch an application like this "in the background"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of making a symlink to the executable, create a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/VSCode/Code "$@" 2>/dev/null &
```

Comment: Yes... Well... *facepalm*